# ReactJS Nested Array State Manage

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to perform Add/Delete and manage the state in ReactJS. Able to do Add & Delete on 'attribute' but not able to update nested array 'attributeValue'.

```
interface filter {
  attribute: string;
  attributeValue: Array<string>;
}

const [filterData, setFilterData] = useState<Array<filter>>([{attribute: 'Filter 1', attributeValue: ['A', 'B]}]);

const removeValue = (index)=>{
    // How to remove attribute value
  }
const addValue = () =>{
    // How to Add attribute value
 }
const removeAttribute = (index)=>{
    // Working As Expected
    const list = [...filterData];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setFilterData(list);
}
const addAttribute = ()=>{
    // Working As Expected
    setFilterData([...filterData, {attribute: '', attributeValue:['']}]);
}
```

[image]

Comment: attributeValue: ['A', 'B] <- mistake.// -> attributeValue: ['A', 'B']

Answer (score 1):

Same concept as what you have for removing and adding attributes - you need to create a copy of your `filterData` array (with object spread syntax here, for example) and then modify the nested objects and arrays. I think you can modify the nested objects and arrays directly (without creating copies via spread syntax) since React only keeps track of the reference to the top-level object, but I like to do it for consistency's sake.

```
const removeValue = (filterIndex: number, attributeIndex: number) =>{
    // How to remove attribute value
    const newFilters = [...filterData]
    let targetFilter = {...newFilters[filterIndex]}

    targetFilter = { ...targetFilter, attributeValue: targetFilter.attributeValue.filter((_, index) => targetIndex !== index }

    setFilterData(newFilters)
  }

const addValue = (filterIndex: number, value: string) =>{
    // How to Add attribute value
    const newFilters = [...filterData]
    let targetFilter = {...newFilters[filterIndex]}

    targetFilter = { ...targetFilter, attributeValue: [...targetFilter.attributeValue, value]}

    setFilterData(newFilters)
 }
```

You should also consider [Immer](https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state#write-concise-update-logic-with-immer), which makes updating immutable data structures easier.

Comment: Thanks, If i use this, is it a right approach? 
`const removeValue = (filterIndex, valueIndex)=>{
    const list = [...filterData];
    list[filterIndex].attributeValue.splice(valueIndex,1);
    setFilterData(list)
  }
  
  const addValue = (index) =>{
    const list = [...filterData];
    list[index].attributeValue.push('');
    setFilterData(list);
  }`

Comment: @SanjuBaba I think it looks like it should work